# How do I avoid syntax error in FOR loops in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.5 and I have the following SQL:

```
FOR temprow IN
    SELECT o.objectid, o.nametag, cor.userseqno, cor.commseqno
    FROM "commuserobjectrights" as cor
    LEFT JOIN "object" as o ON cor.objectid = o.objectid
    WHERE o.nametag LIKE 'commission.video_questions'
LOOP
    INSERT INTO u commuserobjectrights (objectid, commseqno, userseqno, access) 
    VALUES (temprow.objectid, temprow.commseqno, temprow.userseqno, TRUE);
END LOOP;
```

which throws the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "FOR" Position: 3
```

I have never used loops before but according the documentation, postgresql should have support for these types of loops. And yes, I have checked and double checked that all tables and column names are spelled correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `FOR` loops outside of procedural code.  But, in general Postgres (and SQL) is optimized to already do set based operations.  So, you may phrase this as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO commuserobjectrights (objectid, commseqno, userseqno, access)
SELECT o.objectid, o.nametag, cor.userseqno, TRUE
FROM "commuserobjectrights" as cor
LEFT JOIN "object" as o ON cor.objectid = o.objectid
WHERE o.nametag LIKE 'commission.video_questions';
```

Comment: Hmm, you don't seem to have included the value TRUE of the access column which I need to insert.

Comment: @Weblurk You're right; I updated my answer.  You should be able to select `TRUE` as a literal in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: This worked perfectly, but I think you made a typo, leaving a "u" character after INSERT INTO. I'll mark this as accepted, but can you edit your answer, removing the "u"?

Answer (score 4):

`FOR` is procedural code, so you need to use `DO` or use it in stored code.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
  temprow record ;
BEGIN 
  FOR temprow IN
    SELECT o.objectid, o.nametag, cor.userseqno, cor.commseqno
    FROM "commuserobjectrights" as cor
    LEFT JOIN "object" as o ON cor.objectid = o.objectid
    WHERE o.nametag LIKE 'commission.video_questions'
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO commuserobjectrights (objectid, commseqno, userseqno, access) 
    VALUES (temprow.objectid, temprow.commseqno, temprow.userseqno, TRUE);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

This is not the most efficient way to do this task but for other tasks where you can't easily write SQL DO may be useful.